# Run a public web server with domain name [Raspberry Pi]

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I have got a Raspberry Pi which is running a webserver.
But I want to link that webserver with a domain name, so I can go to my website from the public network.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to buy a domain and set your home's public IP as the server address. 
But before you do, you must be sure that your public IP is static instead of dynamically assigned by your ISP. If it is you also need to set your router up to forward ports 80 and 8080 to the local IP of your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a dynamic DNS service.
You need to configure portforwarding on your router and software wich sends ip-adress updates to the dynamic DNS service.
The ip-adress update could also be already a function in the router.
Or use a software like ddclient.
A good dynamic DNS service is https://www.nsupdate.info/ .
It supports also IPv6.